# Is this sentence correct ? Are these 2 sentences bounded correctly?

Tags: punctuation, commas, subordinate-clauses

'Mr. Smith invited Mr. Adachi for a business **lunch, to introduce** their new accountant to him and to discuss their future relationship.'

For the sentence above, I want to ask:

1. Are these two sentences dependent?
2. How are these 2 sentences bounded to each other with a comma and an infinitive? What is the magic here?

Answer (score 1):

It is one sentence with three clauses.
The second and third clauses of that sentence
(*to introduce... and to discuss...*)
start with a *to-infinitive* of purpose, as described here:
[perfect-english-grammar *infinitive of purpose*](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/infinitives-of-purpose.html)

They describe the purposes of Mr. Smith's invitation to lunch.

The comma in that sentence isn't necessary, but I don't think it makes it wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much !